# Importing CSV file without x or y lines but only with street addresses and not using MMQGIS?

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to import CSV file and display it on the map with only the street address and not x or y coordinates?

I don't want to use MMQGIS as it is limited.

Comment: you should specify the geographic area of your address as some country or local government offer geocoding solution

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it could help, but you could try [Geocoding from the QGIS Python Plugins Repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeoCoding/):

> This plugin allows the user to search for an address and get its
>   coordinates (geocoding) using GeoCoding using Nominatim and Google web
>   services. It also allows to get the address of a point by clicking on
>   the map canvas (reverse geocoding).

Comment: It only lets me add one address at a time. Is there a way to add it from attribute table

Answer (score 0):

To display address on a map you need to geocode them (match address to the corresponding xy coordinate).

There are different way way to do it (MMQGIS, the geocoding plugin refered in A_R answer, one of the many online geocoding service, setting up your own geocoding tool using your own data...)

the best solution for you will depend of the location, the format and precision of the address, your accuracy requirement, the number of address to geocode....

To get better answer you should add some precision to your question and state why MMQGIS doesn't answer your need

Comment: MMQGIS is only loading three data with OMS and it only lets me use google map once as it has a daily limit.

Comment: Is there a way to add the csv file and convert it to a shapefile without using x or y cordinates.

Comment: it may be possible to create a geometryless shapefile (a shapefile with null geometry) then to manually add the geometry at the right place but for more than a few address it will be really tedious....